# Socket DataInputStream and EOF Flags : Is there a "conflict" when writing with istream.writeUTF after istream.write?

Tags: java, sockets, datainputstream, dataoutputstream

I am writing a program to transfer files between two computers, but I am not closing the socket for I am using the same socket to transfer other messages (like transfer server's folders organization).

At a certain point, I have this code to transfer files from server to client:

**Server**

```
  System.out.println("Sending " + threadItem.second.getName() + " of " + threadItem.second.length() + "b");

  FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(threadItem.second);

  byte[] buffer = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];

  int count;
  while ((count = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
      outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
  }

  outputStream.write(END_OF_STREAM, 0, 1);

  System.out.println("File sent.");

  fileInputStream.close();
```

And the **client** receives:

```
  FileOutputStream fOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("./received/" + obj.toString()));
  byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
  int count;

  while ((count = dataInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 && !(buffer[count - 1] == '\0')) {
      fOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
  }

  fOutputStream.close();
```

It works, but the real problem is when I send another message from server to client instants after this situation above :

**Server**

```
outputStream.writeUT(new JSONObject()
    .put("command", MessageHandler.ConnectionMessage.OVER.toString())
                                                        .toString());
```

And the **client** receives using:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(dataInputStream.readUTF());
```

But, at this line above I get :

```
SEVERE: null
java.io.UTFDataFormatException: malformed input around byte 1
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:656)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
    at labrpc.secondquestion.Client.lambda$jButton3ActionPerformed$1(Client.java:499)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Somehow `write` corrupted the `writeUTF` or something like that (I've been searching for everything related to it and found nothing relevant), I've tried to remove the `write` from server just to test and these error doesn't appeared, but it's an important routine.

My question is : Does the write and writeUTF are mutually exclusive in socket communication?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This can't possibly work. 1. The file could contain the byte 0, clashing with your end-of-file marker. 2. When reading the stream, there is no reason for the end-of-file marker to be the last byte in the buffer. You need to find a better protocol. For example, you could send the length of each message before sending the message.

Comment: I've had to add the end of file marker as the consumer while on client side wasn't detecting the eof(the file was a .ZIP)

Comment: By sending the length of each message you mean sending the total file length? it's a really good idea, I'll try it when possible, thanks a lot ;)

Comment: I followed your guidelines and it works, thanks a lot friend ;)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it following a hint from [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet)

As I've already had the length of the file, I figured out that I could send the length to the client, so it could iterate only over the specified length, inferring the virtual end of file by the length and already read bytes.

**Server Side:**
     FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(threadItem.second);

```
 progressListener.dmaSend(threadItem.second.getName(), length);

 byte[] buffer = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];

 for (int curLength, accumulator = 0; accumulator < length; outputStream.write(buffer, 0, curLength)) {
     System.out.println("Reading part [" + accumulator + "," + length + "]");
     accumulator += (curLength = fileInputStream.read(buffer));
     System.out.println("Sending part [" + accumulator + "," + length + "]");
 }

 System.out.println("File sent.");
```

**Client Side:**

```
 FileOutputStream fOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("./received/" + obj.toString()));
 byte[] buffer = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];

 for (int curLength, accumulator = 0; accumulator < length; fOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, curLength)) {
     System.out.println("Reading part [" + accumulator + "," + length + "]");
     accumulator += (curLength = dataInputStream.read(buffer));
     System.out.println("Sending part [" + accumulator + "," + length + "]");
 }

 fOutputStream.close();
```

So, it's been possible to write(the socket output)/read(the file input) on the server and write(the file output)/read(the socket input) on the client.